# yii2 user-defined validation of mobile number

Tags: php, yii2

i am new to Yii2. I want to validate mobile number by custom validation function. How can i validate mobile no in Yii2 and how can i use user-defined rule to yii2 and How can we add error message to any attribute in yii2 after form post? Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything is explained with examples in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit your model. Lets say you have the following model:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    ...

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email', 'password', 'id'], 'required'],
        [['email', 'username'], 'unique'],
        ['mobile', 'customValidation'] //<----this will be your custom validation
}

public function customValidation(){
    //perform your validation here
    if(/*has error*/){
        $this->addError("mobile","Your mobile number is not valid.");
    }
}


}
```

the addError method's first parameter is the atribute you want to add the error to and the second parameter is the message you want to show.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help anyone.

Use **pattern match** in Yii2 and validate your input field.

It's going to check and return alert message if number has less/more than 10 digits.

```
['mobile', 'match', 'pattern'=>"/^[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}$/",'message'=> 'Not Correct Format - mobile number should have 10 digits.'],
```